# disabled backbuttom/browser hardware ionic 6 pwa with angular

Tags: angular, ionic, pwa

I am having a big problem with the back button of the web browser when executing my pwa in ionic, when doing 4 rollbacks after a site navigation, the application freezes and returns the browser error STATUS_BREAKPOINT. I would appreciate if you could tell me or help me disable this or control the event.

[image: Error]

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you. Prevents going back in the browser.

```
constructor() { 
    this.NoBackNavigator()
}
```

```
NoBackNavigator() {
    history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event)
    {
      history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y ser cortes con un usuario nuevo. Saludos